# Reading and writing integers to a text file with batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch script:

```
@echo off
if exist test.txt (
    set /p foo=<test.txt
    echo "read: %foo%"
    set /A foo=foo+1
    (echo %foo%)>test.txt
    echo "wrote: %foo%"
) else (
    (echo 1)>test.txt
)
```

I expect the script to check for the existence of the file `test.txt`.  If the file does not exist, the script should write `1` to the file.  If the file does exist, the script should read the value from the file, increment it by one, and then write back the incremented file.

I would expect my output to thus look something like this:

```
C:\opt>test.bat

C:\opt>test.bat
"read: 1"
"wrote: 2"

C:\opt>test.bat
"read: 2"
"wrote: 3"

C:\opt>test.bat
"read: 3"
"wrote: 4"
```

However instead I get the following output:

```
C:\opt>test.bat

C:\opt>test.bat
"read: 2"
"wrote: 2"

C:\opt>test.bat
"read: 2"
"wrote: 2"

C:\opt>test.bat
"read: 3"
"wrote: 3"

C:\opt>test.bat
"read: 3"
"wrote: 3"

C:\opt>test.bat
"read: 4"
"wrote: 4"

C:\opt>test.bat
"read: 4"
"wrote: 4"
```

Why does the variable `foo` not appear to increment as expected?

Comment: Search for delayed expansion on StackOverFlow. Regardless of that I would do this differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use delayed variable expansion so that you get the current values from the calculation:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist test.txt (
    set /p foo=<test.txt
    echo "read: !foo!"
    set /A foo=foo+1
    (echo !foo!)>test.txt
    echo "wrote: !foo!"
) else (
    (echo 1)>test.txt
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified.

If you set the variable to zero first and then read the text file with `SET /P` and redirection, it will overwrite the variable.  At which time you can add 1 to it regardless of what state the variable is in.

```
@echo off
set "foo=0"
IF exist "test.txt" set /p foo=<test.txt
echo read: %foo%
set /A "foo+=1"
echo wrote: %foo%
>test.txt echo %foo%
```

You can even get rid of the `IF EXIST` and just redirect the error to nul when the file does not exist.

```
@echo off
set "foo=0"
(set /p foo=<test.txt)2>nul
echo read: %foo%
set /A "foo+=1"
echo wrote: %foo%
>test.txt echo %foo%
```